# Creating dynamic cards using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm doing an e-trade site with jQuery; however, when I increase then submit one of the products, they all get the properties of the first product. I defined the products as a json to a variable.

How can I create dynamic cards with jquery?

Here is how it looks:
[image]
[İmage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXV2l.png)

Here is the source code:

```js
      $(document).on('click', '.number-spinner button', function() {
        var btn = $(this),
        oldValue = btn.closest('.number-spinner').find('input').val().trim(),
        newVal = 0;
        newVal = (btn.attr('data-dir') === 'up') ? parseInt(oldValue) + 1 : (oldValue > 1) ? parseInt(oldValue) - 1 : 0;
        btn.closest('.number-spinner').find('input').val(newVal);
      });

      let html = data.reduce((acc, {name,value,image,counter,totalMoney}) =>
          acc + `
          <div class='card col-md-3'>
            <img class='card-img-top' src="${image}" alt='Card image cap'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                      <h5 class='card-title'>${name}</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">${value}</p>
                      <input class="money-input money" value="${value}"/>
                      <div class="number-spinner">
                        <div class="input-group number-spinner">
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btn-minus" data-type="minus" data-dir="dwn"><span>-</span></button>
                            </span>
                            <input min="1" class="adet input-number" value="${counter}" type="number">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btn-plus" data-type="plus"  data-dir="up"><span>+</span></button>
                            <div class="total-price"></div>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <button class="submit">Add To Card</button>
                </div>
          </div>`
    , ``);
    $('#list').append(html);
    
    
    const adet = $(".adet").val()
    const money = $(".money").val()
    const totalMoney = adet * money;
    var endText = 'Price'
    var space = ' '
    $( ".submit" ).click(function() {
      $(".total-price").text($(".adet").val() * totalMoney);
      $('.total-price').append( space + endText);
    });
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO!
From reading your example code, you should store the amount for each card separately.
Right now, it looks like the same variables are being updated which results in the behavior you explained. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is that you have (possibly) multiple elements with the class `.adet` and `.money`. However, the `.val()` method of a jQuery collection only extracts the value of the *first* element it contains. See the jQuery docs:

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements...

[jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/val/)